# Metodo para rellenar un array de dos dimensiones

Tags: java

Finalemte gracias a las respuestas he encontrado los fallos que tenia y finalmente el codigo funciona a la perfeccion!

```
public void rellenar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
            if (filas > columnas) {
                int aleatorioFilas = (int) (Math.random() * filas);
                this.matriz[i][j] = aleatorioFilas;
            } else {
                int aleatorioColumnas = (int) (Math.random() * columnas);
                this.matriz[i][j] = aleatorioColumnas;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: La parte de "y sean números aleatorios multiplicados por la fila y la columna por multiplicar por algo" no se acaba de entender bien. Por favor, edita la pregunta.

Comment: No estas ni recorriendo bien el array, ni estas introduciendo datos dentro del array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar no veo la necesidad de hacer esto:

```
int aleatorioFilas = (int) (Math.random() * filas);
int aleatorioColumnas = (int) (Math.random() * columnas);
```

Es suficiente con crear una sola variable que genere un numero aleatorio en cada vuelta del bucle. Por otro lado, no estas introduciendo ningún dato dentro del Array:

```
this.matriz[i][j] = this.matriz[aleatorioFilas][aleatorioColumnas];
```

Estas diciendo con este código, que tu Array debe de ser ese otro Array.

He creado este método que soluciona el problema, solo debes de ajustarlo a tu código ya que no se de donde viene tu Array, ni donde lo estas creando.

```
public static void rellenar(int filas, int columnas) {
    
    int[][] miMatriz = new int [filas][columnas];
    int aleatorio;
    
    for(int i=0; i<filas;i++) {
        
        for(int j=0; j<columnas;j++) {
            
            aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            
            miMatriz[i][j] = aleatorio;
            System.out.println(miMatriz[i][j]);
            
        }
    }       
}
```

Este método **crea** el Array, le **introduce** números aleatorios y luego lo **muestra**. Por lo tanto, depende de lo que busques hacer tendrás que separar las funcionalidades.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias! Ahora entiendo lo que pasaba!